# Collision detection in 2D games

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I am making a basic 2D platformer. I want to get the *relative position of one rectangle to another*.

This is how I do it right now:

```
const float offset = 5;
if (x1 <= x2 && x1 + w1 >= x2)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(y1 + h1 - y2) <= offset)
                    return CollisionType.Top;
                else if (Math.Abs(y1 - h2 - y2) <= offset)
                    return CollisionType.Bottom;
                else if ((y1 <= y2 && y1 + h1 >= y2) || (y1 >= y2 && y1 <= y2 + h2))
                    return CollisionType.Left;
            }
            if (x2 <= x1 && x2 + w2 >= x1)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(y1 + h1 - y2) <= offset)
                    return CollisionType.Top;
                else if (Math.Abs(y1 - h2 - y2) <= offset)
                    return CollisionType.Bottom;
                else if ((y1 <= y2 && y1 + h1 >= y2) || (y1 >= y2 && y1 <= y2 + h2))
                    return CollisionType.Right;
            }

            return CollisionType.NoCollision;
```

Here how this function works (or at least how I suppose it to work):
[image]

Using this function, I often have *collision bugs*, but I cannot understand a global rule of when it happens. I don't think that a bunch of `if` blocks would solve the problem.

**I need a collision detection function that receives two arguments of type `Entity`** (The class can contain any fields or functions, but it must have an X, a Y, a Width and a Height) **The function needs to return the *relative* position of the first rectangle to the second.**

**What improvements would you suggest to my current function** or **is there a better system for collision detection in 2D games where one needs to get a *relative position* instead of a simple `true false`?**

Comment: There is no actual answer to this question because you have not really defined what exactly it means for one rectangle to be on top of another rectangle. Once you define that, then how to implement the function to check for that should be clear. We can't decide for you what the best definition of "a being on top of b" is because we don't know what is most appropriate for your application.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez If I would have known how to define it, I wouldn't ask this question. I have a hero (52 x 20) who walks on (16x16) blocks, and I want him to walk when he is on top of those blocks. Be blocked when he has blocks to his right and so on

Comment: One idea might be to take rectangle B and draw lines through its two diagonals and let these lines divide the world space into 4 quadrants, one on top, bottom, left, and right. Rectangle A can be considered "on top" of B if most of its area is within the top quadrant. A heuristic way of checking for this might be to check what quadrant A's center lies within. You could check this by getting a diagonal and using a line sideness algorithm.

Comment: You might be approaching your problem the wrong way then. Collision detection should be resolved independently of what direction your hero is approaching the object he is colliding from. If, while travelling from point A (in the previous frame) to point B (this frame) he collides with an object, that collision detection should be resolved such that he is moved back to a point between A and B and is touching but not colliding with the object. This is true regardless of if he approaches said object from above or the side.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez So, how should it work in a 2D platformer? I am just very new to game development and collision detection has been my biggest problem lately

Comment: Maintain position and velocity for your hero. Both should be 2D vectors, with an x and y component. Every frame, apply acceleration to your hero, one for gravity, one for if the user is holding left or right, etc. Then, alter velocity by apply acceleration based on the change in time between the last 2 frames. You might also want to do something like apply a sudden burst in velocity if they hit the jump button. Then use velocity to change position. After you find their new position, use AABB collision detection to detect collisions with the objects immediately around the hero.

Comment: I would recommend googling AABB collision detection and resolution or buying a book on the subject. It is too involved to put in comments but is very common so you shouldn't have trouble finding other implementations.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez I have googled it. AABB seems to only give a true/false result. This is not what I want... If I use AABB, how do I know if the hero should fall or not?

Comment: AABB is how you determine a collision. All you need is a true false for that. The part that prevents your hero from falling is the collision resolution. If you fall into a block from above, collision resolution should move you backwards (thus up). If your hero enters a block from the left, collision resolution should move them backwards (thus to the left).

Comment: You should use speeds to determine from where the collision happened. In particular if you are using discrete physics, because these are prone to tunneling. That is, in one update an object could go from being on one side of an obstacle to being on the other side, and if you only consider the positions (on discrete mechanics) you could register the collision from the wrong side. Use the speeds instead.

Comment: @Philippe It seems that your issue is solved. It would be helpful if you were to mark which answer solved your problem, or write an answer yourself explaining what you did to solve it, and mark it as correct. That way the question won't re-appear in the front page, waiting for more users to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is not to check if there is a collision but rather to check if its impossible for there to be a collision.

To do this you need to verify if the two sides that would overlap in a collision are too far away form each other for that to be impossible:

```
if(Obj1.Right < Obj2.Left
   || Obj1.Bottom < Obj2.Top
   || Obj1.Left > Obj2.Right
   || Obj1.Top > Obj2.Bottom){
    //There is a collision
}
```

Using this technique you save on a fair bit of computation when there is no collision because once one of the tests fail it doesn't bother doing the rest since there is no point. 
Do note though that this version counts barely touching as a collision, so you may want to switch out some > and < with >= and <= to have tighter collision checking if that is what you require

Comment: I have fixed my problem by making the FPS higher and blocks bigger. But your solution also works well, you get my upvote, thanks.

Comment: Ahhh then your problem was to do with things passing through other things, you could also look into raycasting to solve that as well if ever you need to bring those parameters back down

Comment: That code can also go through when there is not a collision

Answer (score -2):

You should compare the distance between the opposite sides of both squares and the side which has the smallest distance should be returned. I have written some pseudo code u can get inspired by. The long method/function names are just to make it very clear what they do.

```
CollisionType GetCollisionTypeFraSquare2ToSquare1(x1,y1,x2,y2)
{
    distTop = Math.abs( y2 + h2- y1 )
    distBottom = Math.abs( y1 + h1 - y2 )
    distRight = Math.abs( x1 + w1 - x2  )
    distLeft = Math.abs(x2 + w2 - x1 )

    if( IsFirstNumberSmallest(distTop,distBottom,distRight,distLeft) )
        return CollisionType.Top;

    if( IsFirstNumberSmallest(distBottom,distTop,distRight,distLeft) )
        return CollisionType.Bottom;

    if( IsFirstNumberSmallest(distRight,distTop,distBottom,distLeft) )
        return CollisionType.Right;

    if( IsFirstNumberSmallest(distLeft,distTop,distBottom,distRight) )
        return CollisionType.Left;

    //If nothing has been returned yet it means there are 2 distances which are the same.
}

bool IsFirstNumberSmallest(n1, n2, n3 ,n4)
{
    return n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 && n1 < n4;
}
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work...

Comment: Thats an incredible amount of useless computation

Comment: @TurtleKwitty i dont know if you are trolling.... xd. But your answer is legit the same as mine except your answer is more abstract. And it only checks for collision while not checking for the relative position between the two rectangles.

Comment: Not quite; yes the highlevel algorithm is the same but your implementation does a whole lot of useless computation. Does many more checks, calls on functions therefore needsto build up and tear down the stack each time it checks anything. So no, our answers are not the same apart from high level concepts

Comment: Pls specify. Show me a better implementation which returns the relative position.